# Webpack 2 = Unexpected character @

Tags: webpack, gulp, vuejs2, webpack-2

I'm trying to compile my project with the command gulp but I'm getting that error.

```
Module parse failed: /node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
message: './~/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css\nModule parse failed: /Users/leococo/Site/mtlgigsGood/node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css Unexpected character \'@\' (1:0)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle
```

The file causing problems starts with :

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

This is working if I adopt the webpack v1 syntax but not the webpack v2

### WEBPACK v2 gulp.js (not working)

```
 Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
        resolveLoader: {
            root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        },
        // other options...
        module: {
            // module.rules is the same as module.loaders in 1.x
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'style!css'
                },
            ],
        },
    });
```

### WEBPACK v1 gulp.js (working)

```
Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
        resolveLoader: {
            root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'style!css'
                }]
        },
    });
```

Comment: try: `test: /\.css$/, exclude: /node_modules/`

Comment: I've got the same error

Comment: The problem is that your webpack build tries to parse and build internal module from npm, you can tell that from the path: '/node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'

Comment: The file is coming from that library: https://github.com/ElemeFE/element so the CSS is indeed located in the node_modules folder. But what am I supposed to do to resolve the error ? The suggestion you made did not work

Comment: where did you put it exactly? Does it show the same error or a different one?

Comment: Same error yes. I didn't pu any file anywhere it is juste a file that comes with the library. Here is the path of the file :  /Users/leococo/Site/mtlgigsGood/node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css

Comment: in webpack two you should use: `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'` try this

Comment: Still the same ...

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  },
```

From there,[webpack module parse failed Unexpected character '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717644/webpack-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character)